# 'pip' not recognised command when installing packages

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the `oauth` package from the PYPI list of standard directories by submitting the following code to command prompt:

```
pip install oauth==1.0.1
```

This is to install the specific version 1.0.1 of 'oauth'. However I am getting the following error message:

```
pip is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

I am using Python 3.3 on Windows 8 and have installed Pip via Command Prompt using the code:

```
Get-Pip.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you used `pip` successfully before or is this your first time trying to use it?

Comment: this is my first time trying having just installed it.

Comment: Then can you please [edit] the question to remove irrelevant details (like what package you want to install) and add relevant info (how you installed pip, what OS, what Python version).

Comment: i have amended the code to show python version, operating system and installation method of pip.

Comment: Yep, that's better. Were there any error messages from the `get-pip.py` script? If the full output is available, please include it in the question.

Comment: You might find your answer by trying the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your python `Scripts` directory wasn't added to your Windows path. Typically, this path is `C:\Python3x\Scripts` where the `x` is the minor version of Python you have installed (ie. `3` for Python 3.3 or `4` for Python 3.4)

Once that is added to your path, you can open a new command prompt and use `pip`.

If you don't want (or can't) alter your path variable, you can also add the full path to your command to get it to work

```
C:\Python3x\Scripts\pip.exe install oauth==1.0.1
```

Again, the `x` will follow the above values for the minor version of Python.

Comment: i have amended the path as above and it has worked fine, however within the script folder there is no oauth modules added that i can see?

Comment: They don't go in the `Scripts` directory. They should end up in `Lib\site-packages`

Comment: ok thanks for that. out of curiosity though when i have installed the twitter module some files have been written to the script folder. do you know why that might be at all?

Comment: I do not. I haven't looked at how that module is packaged. Sorry

Comment: I don't even have a Scripts directory in my Python 3.5.1 directory!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the subfolder `\Scripts` in your Python3 instalation path.

Check if there is the `pip.exe` file or `pip3.exe` or `pip3.3.exe`.

In my instalation there is the pip3.exe file, so I need to write `pip3 install oauth==1.0.1`

Comment: i have pip, pip3 and pip3.3 in that folder...do i need to CD to my script location and run the command from there?

Comment: Itsn't necesary.  You can add that C:\Python3\Scripts\ to your PATH enviroment variable in windows.  See this link to change it in Win 8:  http://superuser.com/questions/502358/easier-way-to-change-environment-variables-in-windows-8