# how to set pip environment path?

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables

I ran:

```
python -m pip --version
```

And it returned:

```
pip 8.1.2 from C:\Users\myonl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)
```

So I set my path to the above, but when I try to actually use pip I get:

```
pip install PyQt4
'pip' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' not recognised command when installing packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770105/pip-not-recognised-command-when-installing-packages)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognised+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Comment: The suggested answer didn't help, but the answer I accepted below did work,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time you do `python -m pip`, the second time you do `pip`.

`pip` is not on your PATH, but `python` is. You can fix that, or you can call it using `python -m pip`.

---

Also possible is that you simply need to refresh your console window so it picks up the change you've made to PATH. Try closing your terminal and re-opening it and seeing if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the line python -m pip but written like py -m pip and then the command prompt showed:

```css
Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  inspect                     Inspect the python environment.
  list                        List installed packages.
  show                        Show information about installed packages.
  check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
  config                      Manage local and global configuration.
  search                      Search PyPI for packages.
  cache                       Inspect and manage pip's wheel cache.
  index                       Inspect information available from package indexes.
  wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
  hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
  completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
  debug                       Show information useful for debugging.
  help                        Show help for commands.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --debug                     Let unhandled exceptions propagate outside the main subroutine, instead of logging them
                              to stderr.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
  --require-virtualenv        Allow pip to only run in a virtual environment; exit with an error otherwise.
  --python <python>           Run pip with the specified Python interpreter.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to
                              WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
  --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
  --no-input                  Disable prompting for input.
  --keyring-provider <keyring_provider>
                              Enable the credential lookup via the keyring library if user input is allowed. Specify
                              which mechanism to use [disabled, import, subprocess]. (default: disabled)
  --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form scheme://[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
  --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5 times).
  --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
  --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup,
                              (a)bort.
  --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host or host:port pair as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any
                              HTTPS.
  --cert <path>               Path to PEM-encoded CA certificate bundle. If provided, overrides the default. See 'SSL
                              Certificate Verification' in pip documentation for more information.
  --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private key and the
                              certificate in PEM format.
  --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
  --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
  --disable-pip-version-check
                              Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of pip is available for
                              download. Implied with --no-index.
  --no-color                  Suppress colored output.
  --no-python-version-warning
                              Silence deprecation warnings for upcoming unsupported Pythons.
  --use-feature <feature>     Enable new functionality, that may be backward incompatible.
  --use-deprecated <feature>  Enable deprecated functionality, that will be removed in the future.
```

I was initially trying to install the 'pandas' package so I tried this: py `-m pip install pandas` and it worked.

I hope it helps.