# Having Troubles with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

I already have a pip installed on my computer but whenever I try to install pandas as 'pip install pandas' I get an error: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, how do I resolve this issue? Thank you

Comment: Have you add pip to system environment variable ?

Comment: Follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: You need to add pip to your PATH variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: this will help you [how-to-set-pip-environment-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172872/how-to-set-pip-environment-path)